# is it possible to assign string of text to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, implicit-conversion, string-literals

when we do :

```
char *p;
p="Hello stackoverflow";
printf("%s",p);
```

its will print **Hello stackoverflow** but how this is possible as per my understanding pointers can hold only memory address not string of text ,also why shouldn't we dereference the pointer like `printf("%s",*p);` instead of p ? couz only p mean give us the memory address that pointer hold not the content ! any explanation ! and thanks.

Comment: You just need to look into spec for `printf`. It states that for `%s` format specifier it expects a pointer to `char`, not a `char`. If you would provide a `char` how would it know where the other characters can be found?

Comment: Yes its possible. If you dereference you will get the first character, not suitable for `%s`.

Comment: A string literal is an array. Arrays, in many contexts, get converted (*decay*) to a pointer to their first element. It's the result of this conversion (a pointer to char) that you are assigning to `p`, which is ok because both (`p` and the `conversion from the array`) have the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays used in expressions are implicitly converted (with rare exceptions) to pointers to their first elements.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

In this code snippet

```
char *p;
p="Hello stackoverflow";
```

the character literal `"Hello stackoverflow"` has the array type `char[20]` and used as an initializer it is converted to pointer to its first element. In fact it is the same if to write

```
p = &"Hello stackoverflow"[0];
```

As for dereferencing the pointer p that the expression `*p` has the type `char` but the conversion specifier `%s` expects an argument of the type `char *`.

Thus this call

```
printf("%s",*p);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Either you could use a char * and use that address or you can just allocate memory for a char * and use that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char a[] = "Hello Stackoverflow!";
    printf("%s\n", &a);

    char *b = (char *) malloc(21);
    strcat(b, "Hello Stackoverflow!");
    printf("\n%s", b);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: strcat(b, "Hello Stackoverflow!");  may cause problems, because "malloc()" does not guarantee what the contents of the memory block it returns to you. So, either use "calloc()" or initialize the block before calling "strcat()".

Answer (score 0):

"Hello stackoverflow" actually is stored in memory. So p = "Hello stackoverflow" will assign p to the starting address of "Hello stackoverflow"